# How to display content on via SSL sockets on my web browser whilst using my own digital certificates?

Tags: java, ssl, jsse, sslsocketfactory

I want to make a Java-server where I can simply open my web browser and see "Hello World". So far, I believe that I have set up a server but I don't know why nothing is displaying in the browser.

I used the following command lines to create the files associated with the certificate.

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 360 -alias mykey -keystore myKeyStore.jks

keytool -export -alias mykey -keystore myKeyStore.jks -file mykey.cert

keytool -import -file mykey.cert -alias mykey -keystore myTrustStore.jts
```

Here is my file: Server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class Server{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    int port = 8080;

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "myKeyStore.jks");

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");

    SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLServerSocket ss = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(port);

    while(true){

        SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) ss.accept();
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        String msg = "Hello World";
        out.println("HTTPS/1.0 200 OK");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println(); // Slut på headers
        out.print(msg);
        out.close();

    }
}
}
```

How can I make it display "Hello World" in the browser? I have tried Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: A few observations, not HTTPS/1.0, HTTP/1.0. Try with a simple Socket first, no need to cast the socket, flush the stream, close the socket. Your message is not HTML mime type should be text/plain

Comment: What do you mean with "no need to cast the socket"? Thanks

Comment: SSLSocket is a subclass of Socket (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html)